# How to set up Firebase iOS authentication email

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Having looked through lots of previous questions and looking on the Firebase website documentation, it keeps leading me back to the snippet of code I need in my VC, BUT **not** how to actually *set it up?*.

Firstly in the **email address verification setup on Firebase**
I've by mistake put my personal email address as the 'reply to' email - do I put my personal (not business) email in there/how would I change it? Apologies for any over the top censoring (not sure what is private and not)
[image]

Secondly in my **SignUpViewController** what do I put as the `URL String` and what do I put as my `IOSBundleID`? Many thanks!
[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. To change the email go to Authentication and press templates. There you have some options for your mail.
2. Press the pen beside noreply@yourfirebase.firebaseapp.com.

There you will have a replay to line and you can change all those settings

This is all you need to register a new user :

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: emailText.text!, password: passwordText.text!) { 
    (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error.localizedDescripton)
        }else {
            print("registration successful")
        }
    }
```

To send confirmation email to user make a call after user is created and use this method :

```
func sendConfirmationEmail() {
    // Here you check if user exist
    if self.authUser != nil && !self.authUser!.isEmailVerified {

        self.authUser!.sendEmailVerification(completion: { (error) in
            // Send the email
        })
    }
    else {
          // ERROR
    }
}
```

You could now call the second method after user been created and the user will get an email

Comment: Thank you for the changing email part. Do you know what I would put as my `URL String` and my `IOSBundleID`? - In order to send an email verification to the user.

Comment: You don't need that, only the code I provided should be enough. I updated the answer hope it helps!

Comment: It's saying there's no `authUser` (because I haven't created a variable for it yet) - what would the data type for `authUser` be? ps thank you!

Comment: let authUser = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid 
let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email